# restore_best_weights issue Keras EarlyStopping

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, early-stopping

I am trying to use Keras `EarlyStopping` however whenever I try to use `restore_best_weights` it comes up with an error:

`_init_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'restore_best_weights'`

I am using the most up to date Keras so I'm really unsure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Keras are you using?

If you still do use Keras 2.3.1, please do ensure that your are not mixing `keras` and `tensorflow` versions.

More precisely, avoid using imports like from `keras.layers` import `Conv2D` and from `tensorflow.keras.layers` import `MaxPool2D`.

If the problem still persists after this issue, please use all the imports from `tensorflow`, i.e. from `tensorflow.keras import ....`.

Avoid using the plain Keras package, as it will become obsolete in the foreseeable future; the additional problem is that is nowhere near as well maintained as keras inside tensorflow.

You can uninstall it altogether from your environment.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking the time to reply! Currently I import like: from keras.layers import Dense are you suggesting I now use from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense? And would that be for all of my Keras imports? Thanks again, I'm new to Keras :)

Comment: Yes Catherine, all the imports, exactly, doesn't matter if it is Dense or Conv2D :D. You are welcome.